# Job Search location string shown with Cyrillic characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

[Searching for jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=Python&location=Somewhere%2C+Nice&range=20&distanceUnits=Km) in various locations shows the correct search string, but shows the location in Cyrillic characters.

[image]

Strangely, not always completely *though this may just be because the spelling is the same in Cyrillic script*.

[image]

The search still works as expected.

Comment: More specifically, the locations are in Ukrainian. I see the same thing following your search link. (For the second case, I suspect not all location names have been "translated" to Ukrainian.)

Comment: Well I guess in that case it's *educational* :)

Comment: The issue stems from a different interpretation of `'uk'` by our geocoder and our localization system. It's interepreted as *Ukrainian* by our geocoder but as *English/United Kingdom* by our localization system. I will have a closer look at it, thanks!

Comment: Nice choice for the second pic.

Comment: @AurélienGasser That's really odd.  UK English is almost universally (esp. ISO 3166-1) either or both of `en` and `gb`.  Ukraine is always `uk` and `ua`, depending on whether language or country, respectively.

Comment: I guess since Hell is not a place in the Netherlands, there is no Ukranian translation of the place-name available, so it is left as input (with a bit of capsing). Had fun with that before, where a site accepted English place-names for a country whose written language is "a cyrilic", but then translated them and promptly rejected them as not existing :-) I was simply using the site, I had nothing to do with writing the code...

Comment: @Bill, Hell IS a place in Netherlands. https://maps.google.ru/maps?q=hell+netherlands

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov I should have checked. Completely different problem than the one I saw then. I wonder if there is some "abuse" filter messing things :-) A quick search-engineing did indeed show me "1 hotel in Hell, Netherlands"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has been fixed.

Thanks (again) for the report!